# How to package/publish add-on for two incompatible versions of underlying scala library?

Tags: scala, dependencies, release, versioning

I'm developing a Scala project at https://github.com/jonaskoelker/equate/ which gives you equality assertions for ScalaTest which print a diff of observed vs. expected if they're unequal. This is particularly useful for long strings and large case classes.

I'd like to publish one version of equate for ScalaTest v3.0.8 and one for ScalaTest v3.1.1.

What are best practices for doing so? My web searches came up empty. My own first idea is to publish two things with different names, where the name says which version of ScalaTest each thing is compatible with. Is there a better way?

My way seems rather low-tech. It seems to me that some grunt work could be automated away if the ScalaTest version information was encoded some other way. This seems obvious enough that someone else has probably thought about it and done something about it. I'd like to know what, such that I can release my code the smart way rather than the dumb way.

Comment: People usually inject the dependency version in the artifact name like `mylib-scalatest3.0`. But are there any breaking change in Scalatest 3.1 Vs 3.0 that justify this ?!

Comment: My project at work complains if I feed it the ScalaTest 3.1.1 version of Equate. IIRC it's because some dependencies link against ScalaTest 3.0.8 and so I'd have to upgrade those to use Equate-for-ScalaTest-3.1.1. I'd like Equate to be usable by everyone, even if you can't upgrade your unrelated dependencies. I think the underlying problem is that MustMatchers was moved.